# Solving eigenvectors/eigenvalues of sparse matrix in different ranges successively

Tags: matlab, iteration, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, orthogonal

I'm looking for eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a huge sparse matrix A (250k*250k) that lie in different eigenvalue ranges **without** calculating all the eigenvalues **in between** since it would just take too much time.

---

My consideration was

**Step1:**
I'm trying to find k certain eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix A close to a defined value sigma1. Therefor I'm using `[V1,D1] = eigs(A,k,sigma1)`. So far it's not a big deal.

**Step2:** I do the same for a sigma2 < sigma1 (So I'm skipping the eigenvalues between sigma1 and sigma2) `[V2,D2] = eigs(A,k,sigma2)`.

Unfortunately the eigenvectors V2 of Step2 are not othogonal with respect to the eigenvectors V1 of Step1. They don't seem to have the same basis as the eigenvectors V1. Is there a way to force Matlab to the same basis or somehow feed the `eigs` command with the eigenvectors found in Step1 ?

---

Using the same starting vector for Step1 and Step2 unfortunately did't help. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? I [tried to reproduce this](https://pastebin.com/4VBhbJAa) on a smaller-sized problem, but couldn't. Is there anything special about the matrix? How do _you_ test the EVs for orthogonality? I did it with `dot`...